# NGINX reverse proxy two different server as backend

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I am just new to NGINX.

I set up NGINX as a reverse proxy from `subdomain.example.com` which affects the internal ip 192.168.xxx.x . This works great.

For now I want to reach another server in my network, let it call 192.168.xxx.Y .

The Y should be available under subdomain.example.com/Y .

How do I have to configure NGINX?

This is my first try - which does not work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.x:80;
  }

  location /Y {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.Y:377;
  }

}
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?